# Meteor - Conflict with fields in custom i18n collection, only with multiple publications

Tags: meteor, internationalization

I'm writing an i18n collection, but I have a problem with the fields option for translated fields in publication.

I'm using TAPi18n, but not TAPi18n-db.
My DBi18n collection package work like this:

First, the structure in the database is like this one:

```
{
   page: 'home',
   template: 'home'
   i18n: {
      en: {
         name: 'Home', // used in menu
         slug: 'home', // auto generated from en name field
         title: 'Welcome !' // used in content page
      },
      es: {
         name: 'Inicio', // used in menu
         slug: 'inicio', // auto generated from es name field
         title: '¡Bienvenidos!' // used in content page
      }
   }
}, {
   page: 'about',
   template: 'basic'
   i18n: {
      en: {
         name: 'About', // used in menu
         slug: 'about', // auto generated from en name field
         title: 'About us' // used in content page
      },
      es: {
         name: 'Acerca de', // used in menu
         slug: 'acerca-de', // auto generated from es name field
         title: 'Acerca de nosotros' // used in content page
      }
   }
}, {
   ...
}
```

On the server, if you want to work with translation, you have to pass the lg parameter in options find/findOne.
On the client, if there is no lg parameter in options, it will take the current language from TAPi18n.

On both environment, you can call find/findOne/fetch function with special selector and fields object, like this:

```
MyCollec.find({'i18n.slug': 'about'}, {lg: 'es', fields: {key: 1, 'i18n.slug': 1, 'i18n.title': 1}});
```

DBi18n will transform the call to this:

```
MyCollec.find({'i18n.es.slug': 'about'}, {fields: {key: 1, 'i18n.es.slug': 1, 'i18n.es.title': 1}});
```

Then, we process the result before return it, to put all the translated field on the root of the document and to remove the i18n property.

- find return the normal cursor (we don't process the result)
- findOne return the processed document like this: {key: 'about', slug: 'about', title: 'About'}
- fetch return the processed documents like this: [{key: 'about', slug: 'about', title: 'About'}, ...]

And it's working very well !!

But in my project, I have a strange problem.
First, I'm publishing the Pages for the menu, with some translated fields (slug and name) and another normal fields (template, ...).
Then I'm doing another publication to display the current page, with more translated fields (title, content, ...).

Here is my problem: The translated fields are not published, but the normal fields yes.
And if I comment the menu publication (and I put a static menu), it's working, I can see the translated fields for the content page !
With the menu publication activated, I can see the translated fields just for the home page because this page is not published in the menu.

I hope my explanation is clear, but I don`t think, so I've made a git with a simple project for reproduce the issue:

https://bitbucket.org/Molosc/meteor-dbi18n-example

In the header template, if you remove or comment the publication bloc code, you will see the title value of the current page, but if it is activated, the translation will disappear (except if the translated field was published in the menu publication !)

So I think my problem is due to the fields option, like a conflict with the translated fields between multiple publication? Very strange...

I lose 4 days on it, so I hope someone can help me to find and resolve the problem.

At the same time, I'm interesting to know what about this approach to do it. 
I'm on the right way with the structure of this example and the DBi18n package, or I'm in a dark hole ?

DBi18n package is here: https://bitbucket.org/Molosc/meteor-dbi18n-example/src/2946093f5e7f794322124678c81976d56622995a/packages/dbi18n/?at=master

Thank you so much

EDIT:
In Meteor, is it possible to publish just a part of a sub object document, and publish other part of the same sub object in another publication ?
Meteor will merge the sub-object fields of the two separate publications ?
If not, maybe my problem is right here?

First publication fields: {'foo.bar': 1}

```
{
   foo : {
      bar : 'hey'
   }
}
```

Second publication fields: {'foo.bip': 1}

```
{
   foo : {
      bip : 'oh'
   }
}
```

On the client, a find should return this right ?

```
{
   foo: {
      bar: 'hey',
      bip: 'oh
   }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://meteorhacks.com/understanding-mergebox/). Might clear things up a bit.

Comment: Really interesting. So my problem might be right here. Any idea to fix my case?

Comment: You could pass the `i18n` sub-elements to the top level, publish exactly one of the sub-fields, or transform the result such that it is sent to the client as top-level properties (by observing the cursor). Why not use tap-i18n-db?